# Partial View in Modal popup only displaying first time

Tags: jquery, dialog, popup, modal-dialog, partial-views

I've a feeling I'm missing something glaringly obvious here but I cannot figure what's going on!

I have a table on my view which displays a list of data. For each item in the list, I want to have a clickable link which displays more information on the item. All data required has been passed to the view so this is simply for a display.
What I was trying to do pass the information to a partial view which is displayed as a modal popup each time. This *is* working but only for the first item clicked. Once the popup is closed and another / the same item is clicked, I get the overlay but no popup.

Here is my view code:

```
<td>
    <a href="#" class="viewDetails" id="@hatchSlot.AppointmentID">View</a>
    <div class="ui-dialog" id=@(hatchSlot.AppointmentID + "View")>
        @Html.Partial("_ViewAppointmentDetails", hatchSlot)
    </div>
</td>
```

And jquery:

```
  $('.viewDetails').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var appointmentID = this.id + "View";
    popup = $('#' + appointmentID);
    SetupModalDialog();
    popup.dialog('open');
  });

    function SetupModalDialog() {
    $('.ui-dialog').dialog
        ({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Appointment Details',
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
            });
}
```

I'm not sure what is happening behind. My guess is the first click is overwriting what was already there but as I am pretty new to MVC I cannot firgure it out.

Any help / advice is greatly appreciated. 
I would like to be able to display this information without making another call to my controller.

Thanks in advance for help / advice.

Comment: Just a note - I have also tried this without the partial view - just having some info pop up instead of the view and the same thing is happening - information is displayed on first click but not after.

Answer (score 0):

As I expected, I was missing something pretty obvious - I needed to pass the 'popup' to the SetupModalDialog function....something small but not so small in terms of functionality!

Maybe it might help someone else...

```
$('.viewDetails').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    popup = $('#' + this.id + "View");
    SetupModalDialog(popup);
    $(popup).dialog('open');
});

$('.ui-widget-overlay').live('click', function() {
    $('.ui-dialog').dialog("close");
});


function SetupModalDialog(popup) {
    popup.dialog
        ({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            resizable: false,
            title: 'Appointment Details',
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
}
```